# how to get two locations and send them to server - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, gps, location, send

I started with objective-c programing, and now I can get one GPS location and send it to my server. this is my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    if(newLocation != nil){
        float lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude ; 
        float longt = newLocation.coordinate.longitude ; 
        uint8_t location[BUFFER_SIZE] ={0};

        sprintf((char *)location, "(%f,%f)",lat , long) ;

        [self writeToServer:location size:strlen((char *)location)] ;

    }
}
```

When "writeToServer" is responsible for sending the data.

Now, how can I change this method to get two locations, in interval of 10 second, then send these two locations?

Many thans!

Comment: a question and a comment:  1) do you expect the iPhone/iPad to travel a far distance within ten seconds? is the user in a plane or rocket car?  2) I don't believe CoreLocation can be told "send updates every X seconds"... it sends updates depending on significant change (where you specify a distance filter and desired accuracy).

Comment: Thanks. 1) I don't care if the user is moved or not. but I want only two coordinate. one now and one after 10 seconds (even those coordinates will be the same I want to send it). 2) actually I want to get any changes but think about 1 minute instead of 10 seconds. 3) I just want those locations only once.